# general formula for water pressure

Tags: pressure, fluid-statics

In a Sears & Zemansky Physics text, a general formula for fluid pressure is introduced.

An infinitesimal element is created in the fluid with thickness $\mathrm dy$ and surface area $A$ at a depth $y$. The weight of this element is $\rho A g \mathrm dy$, creating a downward force $\mathrm dw$.

The upward force of the fluid on the element is $PA$ ($P$ being pressure). The downward force is $(P+\mathrm dP)A$. The fluid and therefore the element is in equilibrium; the forces are resolved yielding: $P_2-P_1=-\rho g (y_2-y_1)$.

Where does the $\mathrm dP$ term come from? The pressure in the fluid is supposed to be same at depth. The upward pressure $P$ is the same as the downward pressure, but to the downward pressure the $\mathrm dP$ term is added.

Comment: It comes from $dy$: an *infinitesimal increase* in $y$ causes an *infinitesimal increase* in $P$, that is $dP$.

Answer (score 0):

We want to find relation between pressure and depth in a stationary liquid. If the pressure $P$ is a function of depth $y$, i.e. $P=P(y)$; then we say if the depth changes from $y$ to $y+\mathrm dy$, the pressure will change from $P$ to $P+\mathrm dP$.

$$P=P(y)$$
$$\Longrightarrow\;\large{\frac{\mathrm dp}{\mathrm dy}}=\large{\frac{P(y+\mathrm dy)-P(y)}{\mathrm dy}}$$
$$\Longrightarrow\;\mathrm dP\equiv P(y+\mathrm dy)-P(y)$$
$$\Longrightarrow\;P(y+\mathrm dy)\equiv P(y)+\mathrm dP$$